# Applying Photoshop PSD template for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, photoshop, psd

I have found a lot of `Photoshop PSD or UI` templates for Android on Internet, however I don't know how can I use them to change my Android application UI.

My question is:

- Can we use these `PSD` template files as `UI` for app or those PSD files are just mock ups and we can change UI?

Comment: No, you can't. Android doesn't support PSD files. You have to save them as PNGs to use them.

Comment: those are just mockups you have to implement them

Answer (score 0):

you can't change directly PSD to Android xml. these are just mockups.

1. Convert PSD to png format
2. then implement UI in xml, as shown in PSD
3. take images and icons in png format
4. proper formating in android xml,looks like your PSD.

Answer (score 0):

@user2498079 photoshop PSD files are created by designers to demonstrate the look and feel of your final UI. However, to replicate the visuals provided in the photoshop file, you must export them as PNG files. But mostly you will only need important parts of the screen, like icons, buttons, some images etc. Most of the part id added via android code.

HTH....

Answer (score 0):

To re-iterate what everyone else said above, you cannot directly use .psd files in Android development.
You can however take these Mockups and slice them into smaller components (or smaller image files in .png for example) and use the images as backgrounds in your app.

For example, in my calculator app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tonyebrown.calc8&hl=en_CA), I designed the UI entirely in Photoshop as a mockup, then sliced each element (screen, buttons, background, etc.), exported them in Photoshop, then imported them into Android Studio as resources that I used to build the UI.

The main benefit of doing this is more design freedom.
The downside, you have to work on making sure it works on multiple screen sizes.

Cheers!